# Conditionally rendering an Array Method using Ternary Operator

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, methods, conditional-operator

This is a strange situation but utilizing the ternary operator to determine my array method would allow for much dryer code.

The goal:

```
const result = array. (isTrue ? some : every) (item) => {A lot of logic}
```

The above code obviously wont work but I wanted to see if there was some syntax that would allow something like this?

Comment: You're going to need to be more descriptive on what you're attempting to accomplish here. What is result representing? What conditions are you trying to evaluate with your ternary operator?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#bracket_notation) to access the method conditionally:

```js
const method = (isTrue, array) => array[isTrue ? 'some' : 'every'](item => item)

const arr = [0, 1, 2]

console.log(method(true, arr)) 
console.log(method(false, arr))
```

Comment: I thought about this, but I'm not familiar enough with minification to know if this could break under aggressive minification?

Comment: As far as I know minification doesn't change string values and object methods.

Comment: thought that might be the case, thanks for letting me know for sure

Answer (score 1):

I'd just do it this way:

```
const myLogic = (item) => { a lot of logic };

const result = isTrue ? array.some(myLogic) : array.every(myLogic)
```